# implementing exponent in equation

Tags: java, android

i have an equation;

```
(((nmed - nsub) / (nmed + nsub))^2) *100
```

i've looked through other questions but can't seem to understand how to implement pow() into this equation.

```
private String updateTotal() {
        float nsub; 
        float nmed;
        if(n_sub.getText().toString() != "" && n_sub.getText().length() > 0) {
            nsub = Float.parseFloat(n_sub.getText().toString());
        } else {
            nsub = 0;
        }
        if(n_med.getText().toString() != "" && n_med.getText().length() > 0) {
            nmed = Float.parseFloat(n_med.getText().toString());
        } else {
            nmed = 0;
        }

        return Float.toString( (((nmed - nsub) / (nmed + nsub))^2) *100 );
    }
```

in another equation i'll be doing for another input i'll be implementing sqrt as well. similar equation.
any help would be hot.
thanks.

Comment: What's your problem with `Math.sqrt()?`

Comment: nothing. i just wanted to include i would be using that just in case it may be a different implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` in Java means [*exclusive OR*, `XOR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operation, not raising to the power. You need to use `Math.pow(x, 2)` or simply multiply the expression by itself:

```
return Float.toString(100 * Math.pow( ((nmed - nsub) / (nmed + nsub)), 2));
```

or

```
float tmp = (nmed - nsub) / (nmed + nsub);
return Float.toString(100 * tmp*tmp);
```

Comment: perfect. thanks. i read and read and read the documentation but didn't know how to implement. i had to do this - return Float.toString((float) (100 * Math.pow( ((nmed - nsub) / (nmed + nsub)), 2)));

Comment: You could also use `Double`, like this: `return Double.toString((100 * Math.pow( ((nmed - nsub) / (nmed + nsub)), 2)));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math#pow` but I'm guessing this is homework and you need to implement it by yourself.

The simple approach to exponents is:

```
public int pow (int value, int exp) {
    int retVal = value;
    for (int i = 1; i < exp; i++) {
        retVal = retVal * value;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Of course, you need to handle a few edge cases like exponents <= 0 and integer overflow.  As this is your homework, I'll leave those details for you to figure out.

Comment: If it were not for the android tag, I would think it's a homework, too, but since it's android, I suspect that this is a task of porting to Java from some other language.

Comment: thanks. no. i'm just an old web developer from 2000, 2001 that thinks i can make an app. :p

Answer (score 0):

Just compute

```
((nmed - nsub) / (nmed + nsub)) *10
```

and multiply the result by itself.